# Scrapy get request url in parse

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd

How can I get the request url in Scrapy's `parse()` function? I have a lot of urls in `start_urls` and some of them redirect my spider to homepage and as result I have an empty item. So I need something like `item['start_url'] = request.url` to store these urls. I'm using the BaseSpider.

Comment: did this method work?

Comment: instead of storing them aside, during scraping you can access `requested_url`, check below my answer

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The 'response' variable that's passed to parse() has the info you want. You shouldn't need to override anything.

eg. (EDITED)

```
def parse(self, response):
    print "URL: " + response.request.url
```

Comment: But that is not the request url, but the response url. Scrapy's middleware handles redirections, therefore you can obtain a different url.

Comment: response.request.url

Comment: If the url has redirection, then it gives redirected url not the provided url

Answer (score 18):

The request object is accessible from the response object, therefore you can do the following:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item['start_url'] = response.request.url
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of storing requested URL's somewhere and also scrapy processed URL's are not in same sequence as provided in `start_urls`.

By using below,

```
response.request.meta['redirect_urls']
```

will give you the list of redirect happened like `['http://requested_url','https://redirected_url','https://final_redirected_url']`

To access first URL from above list, you can use

```
response.request.meta['redirect_urls'][0]
```

---

For more, see [doc.scrapy.org](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-redirect_urls) mentioned as :

**RedirectMiddleware**

```
This middleware handles redirection of requests based on response status.
```

The urls which the request goes through (while being redirected) can be found in the `redirect_urls` **Request.meta** key.

Hope this helps you

Comment: I believe all you need is:

`redirect_urls = response.meta.get("redirect_urls")`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override BaseSpider's `make_requests_from_url(url)` [function](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.make_requests_from_url) to assign the start_url to the item and then use the `Request.meta` [special keys](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) to pass that item to the `parse` function

```
from scrapy.http import Request

    # override method
    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        item = MyItem()

        # assign url
        item['start_url'] = url
        request = Request(url, dont_filter=True)

        # set the meta['item'] to use the item in the next call back
        request.meta['item'] = item
        return request


    def parse(self, response):

        # access and do something with the item in parse
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['other_url'] = response.url
        return item
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.5

Scrapy 1.5.0

```
from scrapy.http import Request

# override method
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        item = {'start_url': url}
        request = Request(url, dont_filter=True)
        # set the meta['item'] to use the item in the next call back
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

# use meta variable
def parse(self, response):
    url = response.meta['item']['start_url']
```